# How to get string value from another string?

Tags: c#

I have a textBox1 showing text = 01/02/2013, and I have 
string year, month, day.

How to set 
year=2013, 
month=02, 
day=01
from textbox1

Comment: You'd probably be better off parsing the string as a `DateTime` and then analyzing the resulting object.

Answer (score 4):

```
var text = "01/02/2013";
var parts = text.Split('/');
var day = parts[0];
var month = parts[1];
var year = parts[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to be different and to add a solution that is not splitting the string, here is one converting the string to a DateTime and pulling the information out of the resulting DateTime Object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myString = "01/02/2013";
        DateTime tempDate;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(myString, out tempDate))
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date");
        else
        {
            var month = tempDate.Month.ToString();
            var year = tempDate.Year.ToString();
            var day = tempDate.Day.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("The day is {0}, the month is {1}, the year is {2}", day, month, year);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string.Split to get each string

```
string s = "01/02/2013";
string[] words = s.Split('/');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```
(?<month>\d{1,2})\/(?<day>\d{1,2})\/(?<year>\d{4})
```

I/P:

```
2/7/2014
```

O/P:

```
month   2
day     7
year    2014
```

<kbd>[REGEX DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/yemtMhTCRf)</kbd>

**(Or)**

Try by [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
string[] separators = {"-","/",":"};
string value = "01/02/2013";
string[] words = value.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (void word_loopVariable in words) 
{
    word = word_loopVariable;
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Ugh... a regex is just massive overkill here.